# Twilio: Android IP Messaging Issue

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, ip, twilio

I am building a chat application using Twilio's IP Messaging API's. I am able to send and receive messages successfully for a minute and after that the app stops sending and receiving messages. I am using private channel.

Following is the stack trace for the error:

**Logcat**

```
-1194014160 | 07/27/09:21:06.753 | DEBUG | 5 | TNRawHttp | sendResponse: 403: Forbidden for: 1ebe541611e68a14e4907e58ace9ace9, payload: present
07-27 09:21:06.753 2135-2274/com.example.boya.thunderapp D/IPMessagingSDK(native): -1194014160 | 07/27/09:21:06.753 | DEBUG | 5 | TNRawHttp | Free sessions pool has 2 keys
07-27 09:21:06.753 2135-2274/com.example.boya.thunderapp D/IPMessagingSDK(native): -1194014160 | 07/27/09:21:06.753 | DEBUG | 5 | TNRawHttp | key: https://cds.twilio.com443 has 1 sessions
07-27 09:21:06.753 2135-2274/com.example.boya.thunderapp D/IPMessagingSDK(native): -1194014160 | 07/27/09:21:06.753 | DEBUG | 5 | TNRawHttp | key: https://cds.us1.twilio.com443 has 1 sessions
07-27 09:21:06.754 2135-2274/com.example.boya.thunderapp I/IPMessagingSDK(native): -1194014160 | 07/27/09:21:06.753 | INFO | 0 | TDSCollectionInsertActivity(2) | response 1eb5e5416118a14e4907e58ace9ace9 status 403 body "{"message":"Access forbidden","status":403}" (43 bytes)
07-27 09:21:06.754 2135-2274/com.example.boya.thunderapp I/IPMessagingSDK(native): -1194014160 | 07/27/09:21:06.754 | INFO | 0 | ServiceObserver | error occured id: 17 error: 7
07-27 09:21:06.754 2135-2274/com.example.boya.thunderapp E/IPMessagingSDK(native): -1194014160 | 07/27/09:21:06.754 | CRITICAL | IPM | [listener] onErrorOccured, error 7
07-27 09:21:06.754 2135-2274/com.example.boya.thunderapp E/IPMessagingSDK(native): -1194014160 | 07/27/09:21:06.754 | CRITICAL | IPM | commands: error 7
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Savani

Comment: Check the documentation of Twilio, I guess the access is forbidden for the service you are using. Check their free usage limits.